# Very confused about inserting string into linked list

Tags: c, string, linked-list

I've been working on this project for over a day and I'm really confused. I pray that someone help figure this out. I'm having trouble with the function `insertItemList`. I don't know how to get the `String` in the test file into the `linked list`. This is a homework. The project is much larger than this but i dumbed it down to just what i need help with. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

List.h

```
       #ifndef _list_h
       #define _list_h

      /*
      * Defines a single list item.
      */

      typedef char *ListItemT;

      /*
      * Defines ListP to be a POINTER to a list struct.
      * (Define the list struct in the (.c) file.
      */

      typedef struct ListT *ListP;

      /*
      * Returns a pointer to a new empty list.
      * You may implement this list as a singly or doubly
      * linked list.
      */

      ListP newList();

      /*
      * Creates a new node, inserts the item into the
      * new node and inserts the new node into the list
      * after the current node.
      * Current in then moved to the newly inserted node.
      * NOTE: Impossible to insert at head of list.
      */

      void insertItemList(ListP, ListItemT);

      #endif
```

List.c

```
      #include <stdio.h>
      #include <stdlib.h>
      #include <string.h>
      #include "List.h"


      struct ListT
      { 
         char INFO[20]; 
         struct ListT *Next; 
      }*Head;



      /*
      * Returns a pointer to a new empty list.
      * You may implement this list as a singly or doubly
      * linked list.
      */

      ListP newList()

      {
      // allocate memory for new list 

      struct ListT *newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct ListT));

      return newnode; 
      }

      /*
      * Creates a new node, inserts the item into the
      * new node and inserts the new node into the list
      * after the current node.
      * Current in then moved to the newly inserted node.
      * NOTE: Impossible to insert at head of list.
      */

      //where I'm having trouble

     void insertItemList(ListP LOC, ListItemT DATA)

     {
     struct ListT *temp;

     temp=(struct ListT *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListT)); 

     strcpy(temp->INFO, DATA);
     }
```

ListTest.c

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <string.h>
     #include "List.h"

     int main()
     {
     // Create two lists
     ListP list1 = newList();
     ListP list2 = newList();
     printf("\nList Creation Successful!\n");

     // Insert one name into the first list
     insertItemList( list1, "Alice" ); //Ive never seen a parameter like this before.
     }
```

Comment: What **specifically** is your question?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything in your code that sets the `Next` field of the list node.

Answer (score 0):

List.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "List.h"

struct ListT { struct ListNodeT *head, *current; };
struct ListNodeT
{ 
    char INFO[20]; 
    struct ListNodeT *Next; 
};

/*
* Returns a pointer to a new empty list.
* You may implement this list as a singly or doubly
* linked list.
*/
ListP newList()
{
    // allocate memory for new list 
    struct ListT *newlist = malloc(sizeof(struct ListT));
    if (newlist) newlist->head = newlist->current = NULL;
    return newlist; 
}

/*
* Creates a new node, inserts the item into the
* new node and inserts the new node into the list
* after the current node.
* Current is then moved to the newly inserted node.
* NOTE: Impossible to insert at head of list.
*/
void insertItemList(ListP LOC, ListItemT DATA)
{
    struct ListNodeT *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNodeT)); 
    if (!temp) abort();
    strncpy(temp->INFO, DATA, sizeof temp->INFO);
    if (LOC->current)
        temp->Next = LOC->current->Next,
        LOC->current->Next = temp;
    else
        temp->Next = NULL,
        LOC->head = temp;
    LOC->current = temp;
}
```